# Python - Finding line in text file and adding it and the next two lines to a list

Tags: python, notepad

At the moment I have a block of code that allows me to find an exact line in a notepad file and the add it to `GTINlist`. However I also want to add the line below that, and the line below that as well. I do not however want to import the rest of the file as a list.
This is my code at the moment:

```
GTINlist=[]
GTIN=input("Please enter your GTIN code. ")
GTINcodes = [line for line in open('GTINcodes.txt') if GTIN in line]
stringGTINcode = str(GTINcodes)
GTINlist.append(stringGTINcode)*
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

```
GTIN=input("Please enter your GTIN code. ")
with open('GTINcodes.txt', 'r') as file:
    GTINcodes = file.readlines()  #this seperates the lines of the file into the list called GTINcodes
GTINlist = GTINcodes[GTINcodes.index(GTIN):GTINcodes.index(GTIN) + 3]  #create the list GTINlist starting from the index where GTIN is found and add next two lines
```

Comment: Ah yes, this is also a good solution if `GTINcodes.txt` is not too big and if you are interrested only on the first occurence of `GTIN`.You can store `GTINcodes.index(GTIN)` in a variable to prevent double computation.

Comment: Maybe OP edited the question, but it now says "I do not however want to import the rest of the file as a list."

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use list comprehension in that case. But you can do this:

```
GTINlist=[]
GTIN=input("Please enter your GTIN code. ")
GTINcodes = []
read_ahead = 0
for line in open('GTINcodes.txt'):
    if GTIN in line:
        GTINcodes.append(line)
        read_ahead = 2
    elif read_ahead > 0:
        GTINcodes.append(line)
        read_ahead -= 1
stringGTINcode = str(GTINcodes)
GTINlist.append(stringGTINcode)*
```

Comment: Thank you this is incredibly useful.

Answer (score 0):

The builtin `next()` advances an iterator by one step. So in your case:

```
# setup
GTIN = input("Please enter your GTIN code. ")
GTINcodes = []


extra = 2  # number of extra lines to be appended

with open('GTINcodes.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if GTIN in line:
            GTINcodes.append(line)
            for _ in range(extra):
                GTINcodes.append(next(f))
            # if need to loop through the rest of the file, comment out break
            break
```

---

This can be further simplified by using `itertools.dropwhile` to easily skip lines without `GTIN` in them. `dropwhile` takes a predicate and an iterable, and returns an iterator which yields values from the iterable starting from the first value for which the predicate is false. So:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

# setup
GTIN = input("Please enter your GTIN code. ")

lines_to_take = 3  # first line with GTIN in it, and 2 lines after it
lines = dropwhile(lambda line: GTIN not in line, open('GTINcodes.txt'))
GTINcodes = [next(lines) for _ in range(lines_to_take)]
```